# Rupee symbol not working in firefox

Tags: unicode, currency, symbols

I am using the following currency code for indian ruppee symbol(`&#8377`). But it is not supported in firefox but supports in chrome.

Other Currency codes are supported in all the browsers.

Is there anyother code to fix the problem ?

Comment: Firefox does support that character code when using UTF-8, as well as Robin's answer as well. what verion of FF are you using? and can you confirm your character endcoding.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643800/2142994)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `&#x20b9;` is not supported in your FF(Firefox) browser,then use the following css

`font-family: DejaVu Sans;`

Surely it will work because its working for me...

I have tested that in FF (15.0.1),chrome,IE8,IE9...its working fine....

Example :

`<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>`

Answer (score 6):

This should work better: ₹

(`&#x20b9;`)

Comment: A character reference with a trailing semicolon may indeed work better, but the use of hexadecimal `&#x20b9;` vs. decimal `&#8377;` is immaterial. (There used to be a small difference in browser coverage in the last millennium, but it was the other way around: decimal notation was more widely supported.)

Comment: @Robin: The following code `&#x20b9;` is not working, i think the symbol of ruppee doesn't support in firefox.

Comment: It is supported in Firefox. I see it when I open Firefox. Something else is wrong. What code do you use?

Comment: @Robin: I use the following code `echo "&#x20b9"` and `echo "&#8377"`

Comment: Both &#8377 and &#x20b9 work in my Firefox. You probably have some kind of encoding problem. Did you set everything to be UTF-8?

Answer (score 6):

It is not specific to just Firefox. I am here seeing this on all browsers.

The reason is Windows 7. On Windows 8, It works fine.

You will need to install following update
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898

> An update to support the new currency symbol for the Indian Rupee in
>   Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, in Windows 7 and in Windows
>   Server 2008 R2

Comment: Worked even before system restart after update installed.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough its too late, But I am feeling its worthy to share

After great struggle, we have found a permanent and easy solution/fix for the issue in displaying indian rupee symbol on any Windows OS such as XP, Vista, 7, or any other.

The solution is, you just copy all the symbols(available in "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts" folder of Windows) from the machine(most of the newer versions of Windows such as few editions of Windows7 will support all the UNI code chars), and paste in Fonts folder of your machine . Then restart your machine, it will take few minutes to boot with new changes. Then check now. All the Symbols will gets displayed properly.