# Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML

Tags: html

I am using this code to display rupee symbol.

```
&#x20B9 ; // semicolon is just after 9.
```

for example

```
<td> &#x20B9;{{ od.quantity * od.product_sell_price | currency:""}}</td>
```

But it is displaying empty box instead of rupee symbol in some machines/browsers. For me it is displaying proper but some people shared me screen shot where it is a kind of empty rectangle box.

Can anyone help me why is that different behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the browsers/OS don't support rupee symbol `&#x20B9;` yet.

Fixes:

1. You may use a CSS font which supports it to use the symbol.

   ```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

   <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
   ```
2. Use similar symbol: `<del>&#2352;</del>` => <del>र</del>
3. Try `&#8377;` => ₹
4. Use an image(bad solution but works): `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGbfO.png" width="8" height="10">` => [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)**.

```js
var number = 400000;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'INR'
}).format(number));
```

Or using Icons8 for [Indian Rupee (INR)](https://icons8.com/icon/set/rupee/material).

**CDN**

```html
<!-- Image size: 24px -->
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/rupee.png">
```

**Base64**

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADbSURBVEhL3dUxCwFxGMfxK0UGg4EsNpPZaDZaDcpoMXo13oDZC2CSGGSyMpgsJlJK+P6uri6d+rv/Y/Gtz3BX93/quZPgb3um5FzSwy5SV0IHe+igFTIwT4N20JC+bvyiHjRgFl6lLNrpt5xLetiFSdGKFuGVcfGXPNANq8qIf6YbZJG6aKdJdHgFXr0fesESWksO3ulHdIcOH8NrHZ9q4woNmaIA85o4QUPW8N59UnUcoCH6RGswr4otNOSIBswrYg4NOaMF8/KYQENu6MI8/dGMoCEPDPG3BcELTYVtU4m89QEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
```